# return byte* from unmanaged code (size is unknown)

Tags: c#, c++-cli, marshalling, unmanaged

I've an unmanaged dll that exports the folowing function:

```
__declspec(dllexport) BYTE* GetVolumeData();
```

`Byte*` is a byte array which contains the image data which size I don't know. I need to call this function from C#. All examples that I could find, like `Marshal.Copy` or `memcpy` do need array size (which I don't know).

Is there any way to convert C++ `BYTE*` to .NET `byte[]` without to know it's size?

Can I return it without to copy a data (something like reference)?

Comment: Why dont you export the length of the array? Or traverse it for a NULL terminator if it is there.

Comment: You could keep it as a pointer I suppose.. (with unsafe code or messing with `IntPtr`'s)

Comment: @leppie I didn't write this unmanaged dll. I just have to use it

Comment: @harold that is something I would like to avoid, maybe there is any way to do it safe

Comment: @VladL: In that case it is either a fixed size, or NULL terminated. There is not much else logical to do (unless the dev was dumb). Edit: If it has a known header, that might indicate the length. Not fun in P/Invoke.

Comment: @VladL well you can use `IntPtr`'s and `Marshal.Read` and its friends, that doesn't require the use of `unsafe`